# How to invoke the application Using Mysql Command

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am writing a trigger, in which i need to invoke the external application using the MySQL

Comment: Why would you want to introduce such a blatant vulnerability? Or rather, what do you need to accomplish by doing so?

Comment: i want to run the some batch file to send out a Email to all user....Can you sujjest any other way i can achive this

Answer (score 1):

Looking a your comment, the response is obvious.
Write a program in whichever language you dominate the best. That program needs to

1. Read all email addresses
2. Iterate on the list
3. Send a mail in every iteration

If you promise not to use it for sending spam, I can give you a basic PHP script to do that

Comment: I know how i can i send using PHP.....Problem here is i want to write a trigger which on update in my configuration table should send the mail to required user

Comment: And what will update the configuration table? Surely a program... Make that program call the mailer

Comment: Configuration table is updated by an external Engine written in C++; i do not want to integrate mailing to user with that engine.........

Comment: Make the external engine to CALL the program responsible of sending the mail. You could, in example, write a file in a specific place and make the program responsible of the mail to scan for that file. If found, mail.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest having the external application request the list of users, and then looping through the list and sending the email.  There's no real reason to mix the two.